# Trying to use Google Drive API from native Windows service throws "Not authorized to request the scopes"

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

A bit of an intro from where I am coming from: With as little development effort as possible, I'd like to gain access to Google Drive (scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`) to permanently delete files presently in the Trash.

On a Windows system, I have Google Drive installed and it's syncing files from a directory folder. As files get deleted, they move to the Trash within Google Drive, but they never get deleted hence causing the account going over quota. The windows service responsible for maintaining the files within the local Windows Google Drive folder structure is written in C# and hence I wanted to leverage it to reach out to Google Drive utilizing the Drive API to permanently delete files within the Trash.

**However, when using Google Drive API, I have run into 2 issues:**

1. When requesting the scope "`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`", I get the following response
   `"error" : "invalid_scope"
   "error_description" : "Not authorized to request the scopes: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive]"
   "error_uri" : "http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html"`
2. I thought to have found a workaround for issue 1) in that some recommend using scope "`https://docs.google.com/feeds`" instead. However, when the account owner for Google Drive confirms the user_code, I never get the expected access and refresh tokens. Instead the polling will keep receiving 

   `"error" : "authorization_pending"`.

Just to complete the story: Since I have no UI for the Windows service, I chose to follow the OAuth 2.0 for Devices instructions for proper authentication. The user receives the URL for authentication as well as the user code per email. So the Windows Service upon submitting `client_id` and `scope` will generate an email for the end user, which includes the received `verification_url` and `user_code`.

When using scope "`https://docs.google.com/feeds`", I notice that no app gets added to the authorized apps list on the Google Drive account. However, when using the Google APIs Explorer, it got added to the list. So my hunch is that this scope won't cut it for accessing Google Drive and hence the error "`authorization_pending`" keeps getting thrown.

So bottom line question: **Will Google API simply not get Google Drive access and MUST I use Google Drive SDK instead of Google API?** In that case, I guess, I would have to create some web UI capable of communicating with my Windows service - correct?

Really do appreciate any great insight into the details I have been fighting this for a few nights now. Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you ask the user to authenticate you again after changing the scope?  Are you using the Google .net client lib?

Comment: Yes, the user is re-authenticating. The Google .Net client lib is the **Google Drive SDK**. The **Google Drive API** allows you to access Drive through POST and then polling for status. The SDK requires you to implement a service callback since it's using WCF afaik. The API is specifically offered for devices (in my case a Windows app [service]) where there is no UI for the OAuth 2.0 workflow.

Comment: correct scope with the client lib is: DriveService.Scope.Drive  I would double check that the user is authenticating you again.  It doesn't appear you have been granted access to the new scope.  Or are you using an old refresh token. You will need a new one when they reauthetincate.

Comment: As soon as an old token is used, the user gets a specific error. As the dev I am sending the email for verification that the workflow in general works to the account I own. I do get the "Success! You've authorized..." message from Google. However, I do believe that deep in the weeds, there is a difference between the 'feed' and 'drive' scope. Why would Google Drive respond with "Not authorized to request the scopes" message when asking for 'drive' scope instead? That's one of the parts I do not understand (and yes, I definitely enabled the Drive API for my account).

Comment: As soon as an old token is used, the user gets a specific error. Because that was not authenticated with the new scopes.  Use the new token and delete the old token.

Comment: What type of Client ID are you using, web or native?

Comment: @kroikie - not exactly sure what you are asking. The Client ID within the Google Developer Console reads as "Client ID for native application".